# Problema con mostrar texto en un label al pulsar botón

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Se pulsa un `QPushButton` y sale en un label texto. Pues el problema es que el texto sale solo si cambio el tamaño de la ventana. En cambio si hago lo mismo con un `Checkbox` sale el texto inmediatamente, ¿Por qué? ¿Qué puedo hacer?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * #QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QToolTip, QAbstractButton,QDateTimeEdit,QDateEdit,QTimeEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(582, 456)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label1.setEnabled(True)
        self.label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 12, 291, 91))
        self.label1.setText("")
        self.label1.setObjectName("label1")
        self.pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(144, 180, 112, 32))
        self.pushButton1.setObjectName("pushButton1")
        self.pushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 180, 112, 32))
        self.pushButton2.setObjectName("pushButton2")
        self.checkBox1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 86, 20))
        self.checkBox1.setObjectName("checkBox1")
        self.lcdNumber1 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcdNumber1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 220, 64, 23))
        self.lcdNumber1.setObjectName("lcdNumber1")
        self.lineEdit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 130, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit1.setObjectName("lineEdit1")
        self.horizontalSlider1 = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 270, 160, 22))
        self.horizontalSlider1.setMaximum(100)
        self.horizontalSlider1.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider1.setObjectName("horizontalSlider1")
        self.dateTimeEdit = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.dateTimeEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 180, 194, 22))
        self.dateTimeEdit.setObjectName("dateTimeEdit")
        self.pushButtonTime = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButtonTime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 230, 112, 32))
        self.pushButtonTime.setObjectName("pushButtonTime")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 582, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.printButtonPressed) # PASA con este Boton por ejemplo!
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)# Pushbutton Exit
        self.pushButtonTime.clicked.connect(self.settingDateTime) [font="JetBrains Mono", monospace]# PASA con este Boton por ejemplo![/font]

        self.checkBox1.clicked.connect(self.checkboxChanged)


        self.lineEdit1.textChanged.connect(self.textChanged) # De esta forma se hace dinamico el cambio de Texto

        self.horizontalSlider1.valueChanged.connect(self.LCDBox)

        self.dateTimeEdit.dateTimeChanged.connect(self.settingDateTime)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Testing bench"))
        self.pushButton2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.pushButton1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Push Me!"))
        self.checkBox1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
        self.pushButtonTime.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Date and Time"))


    def printButtonPressed(self): #Este método
        # This is executed when the button is pressed
        print('printButtonPressed')
        self.label1.setText("")
        self.label1.setText("Hello!!")

    def checkboxChanged(self):
        self.label1.setText("")
        self.label1.setText("True" if self.checkBox1.checkState() else
                            "False")
    def LCDBox(self,event):
        print(event)
        self.lcdNumber1.display(event)

    def textChanged(self,text):
        #self.label1.setText(self.lineEdit1.text())  // Sino pongo en el parametro Text, tengo q poner self.lineEdit1.text()
        self.label1.setText(text)

    def settingDateTime(self):
        act_Date = QtCore.QDate.currentDate()
        act_Time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        act_DateTime = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        In_Date = self.dateTimeEdit.date()
        In_Time = self.dateTimeEdit.time()

        #xmas2 = QtCore.QDate(2020,12,24)
        xmas2 = QtCore.QDate(In_Date)


        print("1)" + " " + act_Date.toString() + " " + act_Time.toString())
        print("2)" + " " + act_Date.toString(Qt.ISODate))
        print("3)" + " " + act_DateTime.toString(Qt.DefaultLocaleLongDate))

        nofdays = act_Date.daysTo(xmas2)
        print("4)" + " " + f"There are {nofdays} days until next Xmas")
        self.label1.setText("4)" + " " + f"There are {nofdays} days until next Xmas")
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Por favor se más formal al describir tu problema y centrate en el problema en si. Por otro lado seria bueno que indiques la caracteristica de tu entorno como: OS, versión de python, versión de pyqt, etc

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7
PyCharm 2020.2.4
Python 3.8
Qt Creator 4.13.3